# NSubstitute Substitute Azure storage blob DownloadContentAsync()

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-blob-storage, xunit, nsubstitute

I'm using azure blob container to download container content and do some stuff, here is my code:

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<MyData>> ReadBlobContent(BlobClient blob)
{
    var blobContent = await blob.DownloadContentAsync();
    var blobContentAsString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(blobContent.Value.Content.ToArray());
    var jsonSerializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
    };
    return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<MyData>>(blobContentAsString, jsonSerializerOptions);
}
```

I want to test the behavior of this code which is already called somewhere else, I'm using **.NET Core 3.1** with **xUnit** and **NSubstitute**

I'm stuck with substituting the download process, I already did this:

```cs
_blobClient = Substitute.For<BlobClient>();
_blobContainerClient = Substitute.For<BlobContainerClient>();
_blobContainerClient
    .GetBlobClient(default)
    .ReturnsForAnyArgs(_blobClient);

_blobDownloadResult = Substitute.For<Response<BlobDownloadResult>>();

_blobDownloadResult.Value
   .Returns(Substitute.For<Func<NSubstitute.Core.CallInfo, BlobDownloadResult>>());

_blobDownloadResult.Value.Content
    .Returns(Substitute.For<BinaryData>()); //here it throws System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

    
_blobClient.DownloadContentAsync()
    .Returns(_blobDownloadResult);
```

Always the result **value** returned from the download is **null**, I want to mock it so that I could retrieve the download content and do the needed assertions.

Could you please challenge me on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

`_blobDownloadResult.Value` returns null because instead of providing value to `Returns` method, you provide mock for lambda

```
_blobDownloadResult.Value
   .Returns(Substitute.For<Func<NSubstitute.Core.CallInfo, BlobDownloadResult>>());
```

What you have to do, is return actual `BlobDownloadResult`. As its constructor is internal, you need to do it via `Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models.BlobsModelFactory`. This can look as follows

```
[Fact]
public async Task Test()
{
    _blobClient = Substitute.For<BlobClient>();
    _blobContainerClient = Substitute.For<BlobContainerClient>();
    _blobContainerClient
        .GetBlobClient(default)
        .ReturnsForAnyArgs(_blobClient);

    _blobDownloadResult = Substitute.For<Response<BlobDownloadResult>>();
    var downloadResult = BlobsModelFactory.BlobDownloadResult(BinaryData.FromObjectAsJson(new[]
    {
        new MyData()
    }));

    _blobDownloadResult.Value.Returns(downloadResult);

    var blobDownloadResult = _blobDownloadResult.Value;
        
    _blobClient.DownloadContentAsync()
        .Returns(_blobDownloadResult);

    var readBlobContent = await ReadBlobContent(_blobClient);
}
```

Note, that you can't setup return value of `blobDownloadResult.Content` with

```
blobDownloadResult.Content.Returns(Substitute.For<BinaryData>());
```

it is setup with factory instead

```
var downloadResult = BlobsModelFactory.BlobDownloadResult(BinaryData.FromObjectAsJson(new[]
    {
        new MyData()
    }));
```

As you are using NSubstitute, I suggest to install https://www.nuget.org/packages/NSubstitute.Analyzers.CSharp/ which picks up most of mistakes you did in your code